# grant User permissions based on ldap groups

Tags: gitlab

We are running GitLab EE Version 8.17.0-ee. To manage the amount of Users, we want to add and administrate them via ldap groups. We know that there are some ldap settings in the `gitlab.rb` file. We can definde a user base and also a admin group at

```
 gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = ...

    [...]

#     ## EE only
#     group_base: ''
#     admin_group: ''
#     sync_ssh_keys: false
#
```

But we miss the option to define user groups which we can use to automatically give permissions after those users are assignet to specific groups/projects.
Seen in [this video](http://gitlab%20ee%20linked%20dlap%20group) there was a feature called *Linked LDAP Groups*. But in the newest version I cant find it. Is there any other way to configure GitLab to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an possible answer to my question. We forgot to set the `group_base` in the `gitlab.yml` file. [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap-ee.html#group-sync)